# Promotion Pricing Rules

Tags: promotions, pricing

We are interested in using Magento, but advanced promotion management is a must for us. How does Magento handle the following scenarios?

What happens if I define the following as separate promotions:

- Buy X, get Y for 50% off
- Buy Y, get Z for 50% off

and user adds X,Y and Z to the cart?

What happens if I define the following as separate promotions:

- Buy 5 A, and save 20%.
- Buy 10 A, and save 50%.

and user buys 15 A.